# Is there a modern tutorial for setting up SSL on apache2?

Tags: apache2, ssl

I've been running apache2 for ages on my ubuntu server without SSL.  Now that I want to have some directories delivered by SSL, I can't find any straightforward tutorials that were written recently.  The best I've found is http://vanemery.com/Linux/Apache/apache-SSL.html but it tells me to put stuff in /etc/httpd/conf  I don't want to guess that that should translate to /etc/apache2/conf because guessing based on old tutorials has ruined my web serving before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) is pretty current.  Check out the section on 'HTTPS Configuration' and [what it links to which talks about making your own certificate](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html)